# I want to select a record from moodle database

Tags: sql, database, moodle, moodle-api

I want to select id from moodle database where name is equal to some variable.I am trying this statement but so far its not working.

```
$questionname=  $DB->get_record_sql('SELECT id 
                      FROM {question} WHERE name = ?', array($name));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$questionid = $DB->get_field('question', 'id', array('name' => $name));
```

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API#Getting_a_particular_field_value_from_one_record